# Iterate and search values in a object-literal having multiple levels

Tags: javascript, object-literal

Here is what I want to do:

1. I have a tree (javascript object-literal structure) with multiple levels.
2. I have a value of a particular key of this object.
3. I want to search for this exact key-value pair in the structure and return the value of another key as an output.

For clarity following is my object literal:

```
{
"nodeId": 1081,
"appId": 150,
"displayText": "Welcome here",
"Nodes": [
    {
        "nodeId": 2000,
        "appId": 150,
        "displayText": "Buy",
        "parentNodeId": 1081,
        "Nodes": [
            {
                "nodeId": 2003,
                "appId": 150,
                "displayText": "tCars",
                "parentNodeId": 2000,
                "Nodes": [
                    {
                        "nodeId": 2006,
                        "appId": 150,
                        "displayText": "Diesel",
                        "parentNodeId": 2003,
                        "Nodes": [
                            {
                                "nodeId": 2008,
                                "appId": 150,
                                "displayText": "Price", //This is what I want as return value.
                                "parentNodeId": 2006,
                                "Nodes": [],
                                "nodeCode": "RN_1_1_2_1_3_2_4_1",
                                "parentCode": "RN_1_1_2_1_3_2",
                                "jumpToNode": "RN_1_1" //here is the value that I have with me.
                            }
                        ],
                        "nodeCode": "RN_1_1_2_1_3_2",
                        "parentCode": "RN_1_1_2_1"
                    }
                ],
                "concatWithHeader": false,
                "nodeCode": "RN_1_1_2_1",
                "parentCode": "RN_1_1"
            }
        ],
        "nodeCode": "RN_1_1",
        "parentCode": "RN"
    }
  ],
  "nodeCode": "RN",
  "parentCode": "ROOT_NODE"
}
```

**2. Value that I have with me is "RN_1_1" against `jumpToNode`**

**3. I want to search in this object literal and get the value of the key `displayText`**

I searched and tried few things for this but couldnt get the logic to iterate over the inner `Nodes` objects.

Method I wrote so far:

```
function getObjects(tree){
var searchkey="RN_1_1";
var displayText = "displayText";
var nodeCode = "nodeCode";
var returnText;

if (tree.hasOwnProperty(nodeCode)) {
   var obj = tree[nodeCode];

   if(obj == searchkey){
    returnText = tree[displayText]; //gives me the return text
    break;
   }
   else{
    //here I should iterate over the inner `Nodes` and get the required value.
   }
}
}
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do something like this which works recursively:

```
function findProperty(obj, prop, val, propToFetch) {
    var answer;
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj[prop] === val) {
        return obj[propToFetch];
    }
    for (var i = 0, len = obj.Nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
        answer = findProperty(obj.Nodes[i], prop, val, propToFetch);
        if (answer !== null) {return answer;}
    }
    return null;
}

var result = findProperty(data, "jumpToNode", "RN_1_1", "displayText");
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/EjC5V/

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to your JSON object you can use this way:

```
var searchKey="RN_1_1",
displayText = "displayText",
nodeCode = "nodeCode",
returnText,

treeSearch = function (obj, searchKey) {
              if (obj[nodeCode] === searchKey) {
                returnText = obj[displayText];
              } else {
                if (obj['Nodes'][0]) {
                  treeSearch(obj['Nodes'][0], searchKey);
                } else {
                  returnText = null
                }

              }
            };

treeSearch(JSONdata, 'RN_1_1_2_1_3_2');
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it would work if there was more than one item in the Nodes array.  The OP's javascript may not show that case, but there's no reason for it to be an array if there isn't a provision for more than one object in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I have flattened the array using the nodeId to be easier to search through it.

After you flatten the array you can filter it as you wish(i suggest using [underscorejs.org](http://underscorejs.org/))

Here is the live [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/fTI71xNoLHydY0IOkcYg?p=preview). The result is displayed in the console.

```
  function flattenNodes (obj, newArr) {
    if (obj && obj.Nodes) {
        var nodes = obj.Nodes;
        delete(obj.Nodes);
        newArr[obj.nodeId] = obj;
        return flattenNodes(nodes.pop(), newArr);
    } else {
        return newArr;
    }
  };
  var flattenArr = flattenNodes(arr, new Array());

  function findInJumpToNode(find) {
      for(key in flattenArr) {
        if (flattenArr[key] && flattenArr[key]['jumpToNode']) {
          if (flattenArr[key]['jumpToNode'] == find) {
            return flattenArr[key];
          }
        }
      }
  }

  var found = findInJumpToNode('RN_1_1');
  console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to handle your case. 
Check out this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/5r4Rr/) on jsFiddle.

```
var nodes= [getNodes()];  
alert(getObjects(nodes));
function getObjects(tree){    

var searchkey="RN_1_1_2_1_3_2_4_1";
var displayText = "displayText";
var nodeCode = "nodeCode";
var returnText;

if(tree.length > 0)
{    
    if(tree[0]["nodeCode"] === searchkey)
    {        
        return tree[0][displayText];        
    }
    if(typeof tree[0]["Nodes"] === "undefined")
    {
        return;
    }
    return getObjects(tree[0]["Nodes"]);
}



}
```